# Have command line argument as a default function argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, default-arguments

I have a script I'm running (with a package of modules I wrote) and in some part a certain script executes another with a command line argument. I want the other script (which is exposed to other people, as the others aren't but this one is modifiable & view-able by users) to automatically transfer `sys.argv[1]` to a certain function, say `foo()`, which has some argument that the user sends when calling it - but I don't want the user to know about the extra argument and need to send it himself (in other words, I want `sys.argv[1]` to be automatically sent to `foo()`).

Is this possible?

Example:

```
#my_script.py#
import subprocess
def do_stuff():
    #stuff
    return calculated_var
my_var = do_stuff()
subprocess.check_call(["C:/path/to/user/script/user_script.py", str(my_var)])

#user_script.py#
import my_module
print "My script was finally called, I don't know about any arguments"
my_module.my_func(my_var1, my_var2) #In the background, both my_var1 and my_var 2 are called as function arguments BUT also sys.argv[1] without the user knowing

#my_module.py#
def my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3="""WHAT DO I PUT HERE? I can't put sys.argv[1]"""):
   pass
```

Comment: It's hard to follow you question. Please rewrite it with examples like: I have script.py and invoke it with command line argument and I have script2.py that contains function `foo(...)` and I need to do this and that.

Comment: @vrs Done. Does it suffice?

Comment: Why can't you use `sys.argv[1]`? It would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described should work. Here it is boiled down, hope it helps.

`my_script.py`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python", "user_script.py", "c"])
```

`user_script.py`:

```
import my_module
my_module.my_func('a', 'b')
```

`my_module.py`:

```
import sys
def my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3=sys.argv[1]):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3
```

And then, `python my_script.py` will output `a b c`.

Comment: I didn't realize it myself, such a lovely feature of python. Thank you